# Uniquely Extending a function

Tags: functional-analysis

So I'm taking a graduate course in functional analysis, and multiple times there have been questions on problem sets asking to show that a function extends uniquely to either its completion or to an isometry. What does it mean to show that this is true? Moreover why is it true. How can we take a function, say $F_0:X \to \mathbb{C}$ to $F:H \to \mathbb{C}$ where $H$ is the completion of $X$. I tried reading through the text but its not covered well. On top of this what makes the extension unique? I just need a direction to a proof or a concept that I should go over.

Comment: It means that any two functions $F', F'$ which extend $F_0$ (in the sense that they restrict to $F_0$ on $X$) agree. Generally you will use the fact that $X$ is dense in its completion to argue by continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say the extension exists and is unique, I assume you are requiring the extension to be continuous. In this case uniqueness is automatic if $X$ is dense in $H$. A sufficient condition for existence is uniform continuity of $F_0$ in $X$.  We just define $F(h)$ as the limit of $F_0(x_n)$, where $x_n$ is a sequence in $X$ converging to $h \in H$; we use the uniform continuity to verify the limit exists and is independent of the choice of convergent sequence $\{x_n\}$. If $H$ is compact, then this uniform continuity  condition is also necessary.

Comment: Thats all I needed thank you. Yes I am requiring the extension to be continuous as well